# Change webpage in node js button click

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am currently working with node.js and have this question,

How can i go from one page to the other by clicking the "test" button? I am trying to get from ./Landing to ./Login by pressing the button

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {  Route,  NavLink,  HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./Login";

    class Landing extends Component {
        render () {
            return (

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-test">test</button>

            );
        }
    }

    export default Landing
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Look at the documentation: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: `this.props.history.push(url);` in your `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

J, you can look for the `react-router-dom`

On a summarised way, you will need to this:

1. Import `react-router-dom` dependencies
2. Create `router.js` file, like this:

```
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { components } from './YOUR_COMPONENTS_FOLDER'

const Router = () => (
  <main>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={components.mainComponent} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={components.loginComponent} />
        <Route component={components.notFoundComponent} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </main>
)

export default Router
```

3. Add this `router.js` file into your `App.jsx`:

```
import Router from './router'

...
class component extends React.PureComponent {
  ...
  render() {
    ...
    return (
       ...
          <Router />
       ...
    )
  }
}
```

4. Once you add Router into App.jsx file, remove any reference of your old code for main page.
5. To open a page, you will add this to your component:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

...
render () {
   <Link to="/login">
      YOUR BUTTON or something else to be clicked
   </Link>
}

...
```

Here are some references that may help you:

- https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start
- https://blog.pshrmn.com/entry/simple-react-router-v4-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Hence you can use react router you could add one more route

Look at below example link for more details

```
[CodePen]  https://codepen.io/dwarka/pen/PLEMWX
```